# Views Slideshow missing JS files

Tags: 8, views

[Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) on Drupal 8 gives me all kinds of 404 errors loading the js files. Missing files:

```
/libraries/jquery.cycle/jquery.cycle.all.js?v=3.0.3
/libraries/jquery.hoverIntent/jquery.hoverIntent.js?v=1.9
/libraries/json2/json2.js?v=2
```

Isn't the module supposed to take care of these dependencies?

Any tips on how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only downloading this module does not work. It has **dependencies**. You have not installed the required JS filed which required by module. Those all are dependencies and required by module to work properly. [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2563071) is the step wise procedure for installing Views slideshow properly for D8.

In the procedure steps, if you read 4th step it states that,

> 4. Download the latest version of the jQuery Cycle plugin place it inside the jquery.cycle directory. The filename should be:
>      jquery.cycle.all.js

This is just example, follow all the steps properly then only this module will work properly.

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out. The thing that struck me as well is that the error messages above seem to be a D7 directory structure.

Comment: Whatever error it is showing they are correct, they are as per D8 and it is right errors. D7 error does not starts with `/libraries/.........`,  for this D7 errors will show like `sites/all/libraries....`.

Answer (score 2):

The dependencies are listed here with links: https://www.drupal.org/node/2563071.
Hoverintent caused difficulties for me if memory serves me right - there is no library folder - I avoided using the setting.

The flexslider module is also a very good module to use for images.
Both used here, for example: https://www.aucklandhotel.co.uk/rooms
The testimonials use views slideshow.